# Connecting to Hiveserver2 with R

Tags: r, hadoop

I’m trying to connect R with HiveServer2 using RHive and I’m running into issues.  I can connect to the hiveserver via ssh on our linux cluster and through windows, but not in R.  I have created a test table via the Hive command line interface and pulled the table in tableau so I’m fairly sure the server is working correctly.

Can anyone offer advice on what I need to do to get the connection to work?  Our head node for Hadoop is bigdatann but the hiveserver is running on bigdatajt.

In R I am trying the following:

```
#get off the login node
ssh localhost bigdatann

#Load R into the session
module load R

#start R
R

#should now see > as the command prompt

#load Rhive Package
library(RHive)

#if it doesn't load, install it
install.packages("RHive")

#set environmental variables
#source: http://www.slideshare.net/SeonghakHong/rhive-tutorials-basic-functions 
Sys.setenv(HIVE_HOME="/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.0-1.cdh4.7.0.p0.40/lib/hive/")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.0-1.cdh4.7.0.p0.40/")

#initialize the database
rhive.init()

#Make connection
#source: https://github.com/nexr/RHive/issues/44
rhive.connect("Bigdatajt", 10000, hiveServer2=TRUE)

rhive.connect("Bigdatajt", 10000, hiveServer2=TRUE, defaultFS="/projects/prima/Dan_Hadoop_Test")



#Errors:
Error: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=d3y087, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:204)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:4705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:4687)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:4661)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:1839)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:1771)
```

Comment: Your error pretty clearly looks like a "Permission denied" error on your server. Perhaps contact your systems administrator to make sure you have sufficient write permissions on your server.

Comment: Thanks!  I followed your advice and pinged the admins a bit more.  Some levers were pulled and it was fixed, so I'm assuming your answer was correct.